# Existence of a 2 dimensional $T$ invariant subspace for any operator $T $ on $R^{n} $

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $T:R^{n}\rightarrow R^{n} $ be a linear transformation where $n \gt 1$.Prove that there is a 2 dimensional subspace $M \subseteq R^{n}$ such that $T(M)\subseteq M $

My attempt :

Let $ B=\{v_1,v_2,....,v_n \} $ be an ordered basis. Let T-annhilators of $v_1 $ and $v_2 $ be $p_1 (x)$ and $p_2(x) $ respectively.

If $deg(p_1)=deg(p_2)=1 $ then they are eigen vectors and the required subspace is $L(\{v_1,v_2\})$

If $max\{deg(p_1),deg(p_2)\}=m\ge 2$  , then WLOG let us assume $deg(p_1)=m$ .Then the T-cyclic subspace generated by $v_1$ i.e $Z(v_1,T) $ is an $m$-dimensional $T$ invariant subspace.

I claim $m=2$ i.e $p_1$ is quadratric polynomial.Since the underlying feild of scalars is $R$ highest degree irreducible polynomial is 2 .

So $p_1(x)=f_1(x)f_2(x)..f_k(x)$. where each $f_i $ are linear or atmost irreducible quadratics.

Then since $p_1(T)v_1=0$, can I say that $f_t(T)v_1=0$ for some $t$ thus contradicting the minimality of $p_1$.

Presuming I am correct in my arguments please help me in giving this last finishing touch. Or if I am wrong somewhere , please point it out. Thanks beforehand.